# Trim/Clip scope by a defined curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hy

I have to plot a vector field inside region in tikz. The arrows of the vector field should not appear outside the region.

The region is the interior of :

```
\draw [black, fill=white] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(ar) (br) (cr) (dr) (er)};
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get yourself familiarised with our format.

Comment: Also kindly post a complete MWE starting from `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you looked up the `\clip` command in the [TikZ/PGF Manual](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)?